# Can't start ElasticSearch on TFS 2017.1

Tags: elasticsearch, tfs

currently i can't start ElasticSearch 2.4.1 on TFS 2017.1 on Windows Server 2012

The log file say access denied, but the folder "E:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore" has 775 rights

```
elasticsearch-service-x64-stderr.xxxx-xx-xx.log

2017-04-27 07:20:56 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Exception in thread "main" tion: Unable to access 'path.data' (E:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore)
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:90)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(WindowsLinkSupport.java:259)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:836)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:333)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:256)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:183)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

The TFS_Serach_TFS.log

```
[ERROR][bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (E:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:316)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:256)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:183)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:90)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(WindowsLinkSupport.java:259)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:836)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:333)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
    ... 7 more
```

My configuration for ElasticSearch (elasticsearch.yml)

```
{
    "cluster.name": "TFS_Search_${COMPUTERNAME}",
    "node.name": "${COMPUTERNAME}",
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "path.data": "${SEARCH_ES_INDEX_PATH}",
    "http.port": 9200,
    "discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled": false,
    "network.host": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

Everyone an idea, how can I resolve these problem.

EDIT:
Server Log, when i try to start Elasticsearch service

```
'AccountFaultInJob' failed with error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Common.SearchPlatformException: ES Exception: Unknown Exception Err: [Nest.GetAliasesResponse]. Raw response:
```

Comment: it seems that the user that runs the `elasticsearch` process is not allowed to access the folder `E:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore` (i.e. `AccessDeniedException`). Fix the access rights and try again.

Comment: I have give everyone full access to the "E:\TfsData" folder and all sub folders, the problem is still there

Comment: Still `AccessDeniedException`?

Comment: Yes, i get the same error in the elasticsearch log file

Comment: Is there a way to get a verbose output from the elasticsearch program/job ?

Comment: Does the account of the **elasticsearch-service-x64** be a domain account and does this account be an administrator of your TFS server? Could you please [Unconfigure Code Search](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/search/code/administration#unconfigure-code-search-in-team-foundation-server) and install it again?

Comment: Does the account have "Log on as a service" permission?

Answer (score 0):

after long time i have fix the problem

There was a few problems

1. The folder for the search index have all needed access rights, but under windows the drive have separate access rights, so the account for the search service need access rights to the drive.
2. The port 8000 and **9200** was bind to the TFS, I removed the binding to the port 9200 from the IIS. You can found the bindings under IIS-Manger -> TFS -> Sites
3. The ElasticSearch service has always used the Port **9201** on the installation, after I have remove the port binding from the IIS and reinstall ElasticSearch, it use the Port 9200.
4. After it was all okay i have start a complete re-indexing via the PowerShell script. This will take a few hours. The code search page will always show an error before the indexing is complete.

Important URLs for TFS admins:

- on TFS -> ES Index -> http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v
- on TFS -> ES Status -> http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v
- TFS Status, Jobs, etc. -> http://[Server]:8080/tfs/_oi/
  (you need full TFS admin rights)

Hope it can help you